# C# - WiX windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, wix

I have a WiX setup project that takes the output of a c# windows service.
I install the project and the service is created properly (in services.msc) and I can see the process in the task manager.

My Windows Service is a Server that binds to an IP:PORT and just listens for connections.

When I install the service using WiX the binding of the IP:PORT doesn't seem to occur, yet no error is given. I check netstat and I don't see the IP:PORT in the list.

On the other hand, when I use InstallUtil, it works properly.

Am I doing something wrong in WiX or is there something I need to change in my Service for it to work as it should?

Using .NET 4.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same data set, whether you are using the [SC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) command, the [ServiceInstall Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or an installer class custom action launched by InstallUtil, the end state should be the same.

So either the data set isn't the same  (username, password ectera ) or you have additional registration code being done in the custom action that's not expressed by the ServiceInstall table.

It's hard to troubelshoot further without observing on a VM or looking at the installer custom action code.  I can say though that I've installed hundreds of Windows (NT) Services authored in .NET over the years and ServiceInstal is more then capable.

Comment: I wanted to answer, but I can't due to my reputation.

here's my answer in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GtxQBvND

Comment: Based on that it looks like you are creating a servcie and creating an EventLog / EventSource. You have to use the Util extension in WiX and declare the EventSource element to do this. Without the event source your service is probably throwing an exception on startup. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_eventsource.htm

Comment: Good point. I had no EventSource in my WiX. Even after adding it however, it's still not binding. I'm really puzzled...

Comment: Sorry, it takes detailed profiling and troubleshooting to resolve these issues.  Your cause/solution will be very specific so it's hard to answer from here.